# How can I split my list into a list of lists given a condition?

Tags: python, list

Can someone help me split this list into a list of lists?

For example, given this input:

```py
['Na', '2', ' ', 'C', ' ', 'O', '3']
```

I want this output:

```py
[['Na', '2'], ['C'], ['O','3']]
```

Comment: How do you want to split up the list? What are the conditions?

Comment: loop over and make a new sublist every time you see a space?

Comment: Says "given a condition". Doesn't give us a condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to generate the desired sublists:

```py
from itertools import groupby
[list(group) for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x == ' ') if not key]
```

This outputs:

```py
[['Na', '2'], ['C'], ['O', '3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['Na', '2', ' ', 'C', ' ', 'O', '3']
lst_of_lsts = []
sublist = []
for item in lst:
    if item != " ":
        sublist.append(item)
    else:
        lst_of_lsts.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
if sublist != []:
     lst_of_lsts.append(sublist)
```

Comment: This is true, ill fix it, thank you

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Depends. `'Na2 C O '.split(' ')` for example also results in an empty string at the end. The question only talks about splitting, not about omitting empty sublists.